# Making a file out of all the files with given a string

Tags: bash, shell, syntax, sh

> Create a file that includes the content of all the files in the current folder that has a given string (in say argument 1), the data will be in it one after the other (each file appended to the end). The name of the file will be the given string.

I thought of the following but it doesn't work:

```
grep $1 * >> fnames #places all the names of the right files in a file
for x in fnames
do
  cat x >> $1 #concat the files from the list
done
rm fnames
```

On the same note, is there a site that has solved exercises like this or examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about (assuming you aren't worried about files with spaces or newlines or shell globs/etc. in their names since those will not work here correctly):

```
for O in $(grep -l $1 *)
 do
   cat "$O" >> $1
 done
```

Comment: It's simple I like this. This`$(grep -l $1 *)` basically stores the names of all the files in a list?

Comment: @kuhaku The `$(...)` captures the output of the `grep` command and gets replaced by that output in the outer `for` loop. That being said this is entirely unsafe for files with spaces, newlines or shell metacharacters in their names.

Comment: It's ok to assume the names are safe here. Why the `" "` are needed there?

Comment: Technically they're not needed, as @Etan commented this is not safe for file names with spaces and non-printable characters.

Comment: The quotes are needed to keep the variable expansion as one word and to not have the shell evaluate metacharacters/etc. in the variable's value. In this case, since those have already been eaten/exapnded by the shell in the loop phase the quotes aren't protecting anything of value here. (If the loop were fixed to be safe then the quotes would still be necessary).

Comment: @kuhaku This answer is strictly less correct then the other answer. Just be aware of that.

Comment: @JohnKuhns did you try to run it? It creates the new file but it's empty and  it says "cat: x: no such file or directory" . The folder isn't empty and when I run `(grep -l foo *)` in the terminal it finds files.

Comment: As @Etan pointed out, the quotes are needed. I ran it with the quotes this morning and it ran just fine. I don't see a case where it would fail. It should be $x, not just x.

Comment: @kuhaku `cat $x` not `cat x` you want the variable value not the letter `x`. And `$(grep ...)` is not the same as `(grep ...)`. The former is command substitution; the latter is just a sub-shell.

Comment: Yup that was the problem. This language is unbearable... Thanks to you two. BTW, is there a real world use of Bash in companies?

Comment: Bash is just a command interpreter for Unix and Unix like operating systems. The Unix utils, like grep, sed, awk, uniq, sort, tr, etc. save tons of time doing mundane things. Even if you end up working in a Windows environment they can still save you tons of time since there are ports for Windows. If you're going to be a developer, these tools are very important. If you're going to be on the systems end they're vital.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this using [**process substitution**](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst):

```
shopt -s nullglob

while read -r file; do
    cat "$file"
done < <(grep -l "search-pattern" *) > /path/to/newfile
```

This is assuming your directory only has files and no sub-directories.

You will need to use `find` with `grep` if there are sub-directories as well:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec grep -q "search-pattern" {} \; -print0 |
     xargs -0 cat > /path/to/newfile
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<<` instead of `< <`?

Comment: No it must be `< <` for [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst)

Comment: Also, can you explain a bit what happens? why does the output of grep redirect to two places?

Comment: Check the link I provided in previous comment. `grep`. It basically treats a command's output like a file.

Comment: `xargs` would likely be a better approach to this problem as it would involve many fewer executions of `cat` (only one for all but the very very largest of directories).

Comment: Also `nullglob` is not necessary here as `grep` will simply not match on the unexpanded `*` file. And `-maxdepth 1` doesn't seem correct there.

Comment: Thanks @EtanReisner for the nice tip. Yes `xargs` will be better with `find`. Edited now.